# What does it mean when netstat outputs a dash in pid / program name column?

Tags: socket, netstat

Here is some lightly modified output from netstat (I removed the addresses and names)

```
a@xxxxx:/app# netstat -p
Active Internet connections (w/o servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 xxxxx:38922             foo.bar.baz:9007        TIME_WAIT   -          
tcp        0      0 xxxxx:33180             foo.bar.baz:27017       ESTABLISHED 7/java
```

My question is what the dash under PID/Program name means.  The second one is much clearer, PID 7 which is a java process.

From the man page:

```
-p, --program
Show the PID and name of the program to which each socket belongs.
```

Does this mean that the socket was closed or abandoned or something?

Comment: Yes; TIME_WAIT state is an endpoint that was closed by the process that was using it, but may still have traffic in transit on the network so the addr/port cannot be reused yet because there may still be traffic in transit; see next door https://superuser.com/questions/173535/what-are-close-wait-and-time-wait-states and https://superuser.com/questions/819373/keep-alive-established-and-time-wait-semantics . Since it isn't opened by a process, there is no process id or program to be shown.